# Probability distribution that an event (e.g. a meeting or a call) is in progress

Tags: probability-distributions

I am considering events. They can be meetings, phone calls, etc. Let's say that a person is calling someone.

Having both the probability distribution of event's start time and probability distribution of an event's duration, can the probability distribution that event is in progress in a given moment be calculated analytically?

In other words: can I calculate the probability that the person of interest is in a call?

Settings of this problem are very similar to the one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988145/probability-distribution-over-time-of-an-event-dependent-on-a-prior-event), but the measure of interest is different, and I cannot grasp a solution for my problem from that one.

I created a computational solution, but I'm wondering is there any theoretical framework you can point me to.

Comment: Can you describe your computational solution? Your problem is thorny. The start time distribution would be bimodal with a peak in the early morning and a smaller peak in the early afternoon. Also, the duration distribution depends on the start time (Parkinson's Law).

Comment: Oh, that was quick, thank you for the comment!

Comment: My naïve solution is based on sampling: I've created many samples of the event, then calculated the probability in discrete time intervals. 
You are right, the observed distribution of the start time exhibits multimodality. But, I found a suitable approximation for PDF, no problem for that. 
I am wandering if there is a procedure to combine two analytical forms of PDFs for start time and duration into PDF that describe probability of a call in progress.